# How to parse the json result from getThingShadow, using AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I'm having some problem parsing the result from AWS getThingShadow using AWS SDK and nodejs. It returns data and it looks similar to Json except that it has the text payload in the beginning, I'm thinking that's why i can parse it properly. On the other hand i suspect there must exist some feature as part of AWS SDK that can do this for me? Unfortunately i haven't found any information on that. What would you think is the easiest way to do this?

```
   var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: 'myEndPoint'});
   iotdata.getThingShadow(params, function (err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else
        {
            console.log(data);           // successful response
```

The data looks like this:
payload {"state":{"desired":{"GPIO1":"0","GPIO5":"0","GPIO6":"0","GPIO13":"0"},"reported":
{"GPIO1":"8","GPIO5":"0"...

Of course i could try to "manually" remove the first text (payload) and then parse as normal json, but that doesn't sound like the right way.

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response looks a little odd because I think it is actually an object to begin with. `payload` is the key and the `value` is the string that you need to parse.

I think you may be able to do something like this if that is true and the payload is itself an object.

```
const test = {payload: '{"state":{"desired":{"GPIO1":"0","GPIO5":"0","GPIO6":"0","GPIO13":"0"},"reported": {"GPIO1":"8","GPIO5":"0"}}}'}

console.log('typeof test', typeof test) // assuming this returns object

JSON.parse(test.payload)

{
  state: {
    desired: { GPIO1: '0', GPIO5: '0', GPIO6: '0', GPIO13: '0' },
    reported: { GPIO1: '8', GPIO5: '0' }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, I see some perfect looking json now. Many thanks for the help!